# Greenplum demo cluster regression test installcheck-good is not working

Tags: database, greenplum

Greenplum demo cluster regression test installcheck-good is not working

I have built  the code for greenplum open source project as per steps given at https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb. I could build the code. However there is a section “Basic GPDB source configuration, compilation, gpdemo cluster creation and test execution example”. While running installcheck-good which is supposed to run a few regression test to make sure that cluster is installed properly.
However facing issue with some select statements failing. I am not clear at what steps those database tables are expected to create. So not sure how to fix this issue. Any help on this appreciated. Below is log from run :

[priti@priti-vm gpdb-master]$ make installcheck-good
make -C src/test installcheck-good
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/priti/gpdb-master/src/test'
make -C regress installcheck-good
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/priti/gpdb-master/src/test/regress'
make -C ../../../src/port all
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/priti/gpdb-master/src/port'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for`all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/priti/gpdb-master/src/port'
make -C ../../../contrib/spi refint.so autoinc.so
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/priti/gpdb-master/contrib/spi'
make[3]: `refint.so' is up to date.
make[3]:`autoinc.so' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/priti/gpdb-master/contrib/spi'
rm -rf ./testtablespace
mkdir ./testtablespace
./checkinc.py
Greenplum INCLUDEDIR:    /root/greenplum/gpdb-master/include
Greenplum PKGINCLUDEDIR: /root/greenplum/gpdb-master/include/postgresql
Checking includes...
Include files are ok
if [ -z "" ]; then \
        ./pg_regress --inputdir=. --multibyte=   --init-file=./init_file  --psqldir=/home/priti/gpdb-master/bin --schedule=./parallel_schedule --schedule=./greenplum_schedule --srcdir=/home/priti/gpdb-master/src/test/regress; \
        else \
        bash kerberos/setup_test.sh; \
        PGUSER="gpadmin/kerberos-test" ./pg_regress --inputdir=. --multibyte=   --init-file=./init_file  --psqldir=/home/priti/gpdb-master/bin --schedule=./parallel_schedule --schedule=./greenplum_schedule --srcdir=/home/priti/gpdb-master/src/test/regress --host=`hostname`; \
        fi
(using postmaster on Unix socket, port 15432)
ERROR:  relation "gp_segment_configuration" does not exist
LINE 1: select content, role, status, hostname from gp_segment_confi...
                                                    ^
ERROR:  relation "gp_segment_configuration" does not exist
LINE 1: ... gscp.mode, gscp.status, gscp.preferred_role from gp_segment...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  relation "gp_segment_configuration" does not exist
LINE 1: ... gscp.mode, gscp.status, gscp.preferred_role from gp_segment...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  relation "gp_segment_configuration" does not exist
LINE 1: ... gscp.mode, gscp.status, gscp.preferred_role from gp_segment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this error though I don't know what is exact reason.
However first time, I had faced lot of issues to do all steps in one shot ( lot of prerequisite were not clear ) and therefore I might have resulted at the end in this error.
So I took a clean machine and tried all steps as below. Also make sure that below prerequisite packages are added before starting first steps.

Prerequisites 
1. create a new user as gpadmin. set password for that user
2. Make sure that password less ssh is working from root user as well as from same user to localhost.
3. Do all steps as part of new user only.
4. install below packages first
yum install -y  zlib*
yum install -y  libcurl-devel.x86_64 0:7.19.7-37.el6_5.3
yum install -y  bzip2-devel*
yum install -y bison*
yum install -y  flex*
yum install -y gcc
yum install python-crypto python-paramiko

after all this start with below steps and then regression test will also work. 
su - gpadmin
Cd /home/gpadmin/gpdb-master
./configure --prefix=/home/gpadmin/gpdb-master
Make
make install
source /root/greenplum/gpdb-master/greenplum_path.sh
cd gpAux/gpdemo
make cluster
source gpdemo-env.sh
make installcheck-good

Thanks
Priti